# scripting: create a user input form?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting, actionscript

I havent been able to find any references that this should be possible, maybe you can assist ?

What i would like to do is to add a user interface for our designers when dealing with a specific object (box object), its like a electrical floor drawing where they will add boxes to many segments of the drawing.

The thought was to import a CSV file with a list of predefined boxes with the following format :

Name, BoxType, Color, Floor

When all has been done and they changed what they want, we do another export of the list.

1)

When adding a box object i would like to be able to pop up a form, like a small properties form, where they are able to select from a dropdown box one of the predefined box-records from the imported list.

2)

Would also like them to be able to change each of the 4 values selected, manually in a form, so ex. they can give the box its own name ( different from what it was in the imported records ) - i imagine just a form popping up ex on rightclick or hotkey where they can change the 4 values as they wish, ex. changing what floor it is located on.

Is this possible at all in any way in Illustrator using script or SDK or somekind of other method ?

Hope you can help.

Comment: it sounds scriptable, if you want to give it shot, find all about scripting here, post here if you need assistance http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html

Answer (score 2):

This is hard to find reference for in the adobe docs, at least in the short time I scanned them. However, it appears the basic idea is:

```
var dlg = new Window("dialog{text:'yadayada'}");
dlg.show();
```

A more in depth example can be found on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23858055/jsx-illustrator-script-set-radio-option-as-default-when-the-script-loads)

Further reading, google: "illustrator dialog jsx"